# Eliminar un atributo si no está definida la variable

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando omitir un atributo con `ngIf`, o algo similar en Angular:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control-mat"
    *ngIf="recomendacion!=undefined" [placeholder]="recomendacion" >
```

Esto es lo que tengo ahora mismo, pero en vez de omitir el atributo `placeholder`, me omite todo el elemento.

¿Es posible aplicar algo similar que funcione sobre atributos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La directiva [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) gestiona que aparezca o no el elemento completo, por eso aparece o no el elemento dependiendo del valor de `recomendacion`.

A continuación muestro cómo usar `recomendacion` para que el atributo aparezca solo cuando la variable esté definida:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control-mat"
    [attr.placeholder]="recomendacion" />
```

Puedes consultar la [documentación de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-an-attribute):

> When the expression resolves to `null` or `undefined`, Angular removes the attribute altogether.

En castellano:

> Cuando la expresión resuelve a `null` o `undefined`, Angular elimina por completo el atributo.

Comment: Esto no omite el atributo, sólo pone un valor `void` al mismo.

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías mirar mi última edición? Creo que es lo que buscas.

Comment: PD: Gracias @MauricioContreras por tu apunte, he mejorado la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora si, todos contentos. Excelente respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes condicionar un atributo dentro de este mismo.

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="5" class="form-control-mat" [placeholder]="recomendacion ? recomendacion : null" >
```

En el ejemplo que te pongo, lo que hacemos es establecer el atributo `placeholder` en caso de que recomendación exista, en caso contrario devolvemos un `null`, lo que desactiva el atributo.

Para la condicional, por si no las has usado nunca:

```
Condición (if = ?) caso afirmativo (else = :) caso negativo
```

Lo mejor de esto es que te deja condicionar el valor del atributo, muy útil para trabajar con css, clases y estados de los elementos.

Comment: Esto no omite el atributo, sólo pone un valor `void` al mismo.

Comment: puede ser null, '' o lo que sea. el atributo seguirá pintándose pero sin valor. Si quieres quitarlo por completo se debería condicional el tag entiendo, o hacerlo por javascript el agregado del atributo. @MauricioContreras, no?